# Run OSGi Console of RCP Application (NOT the Host OSGi console)

Tags: eclipse, plugins, osgi, bundle, rcp

I need to check whether certain bundles loaded at startup inside my RCP Application. I know there is a "Host OSGi Console" that shows the states of all Plug-Ins within the Eclipse IDE, but I am not interested in those.

I performed the following steps to get the OSGi Console of my application itself:

1. Added the Plug-In "org.eclipse.equinox.console"
2. Created a OSGi Framework Configuration: Run Configuration -> OSGi Framework -> MyNewConfiguration
3. Run the configuration

When I validate the Plug-Ins, it says "Missing constraint: import package org.eclipse.felix.service.command". Where can I find this bundle?

Is this the correct way to open the OSGi Console of my custom RCP application? I'm not able to export the application as a product, so I can't run it outside of the Eclpse IDE.

Comment: org.**eclipse**.felix or org.**apache**.felix? The org.apache.felix plugins are included in Eclipse.

Answer (score 6):

Include bundles

1. org.eclipse.eqinox.console,
2. org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,
3. org.apache.felix.gogo.shell

in your run configuration.
Also add option `-console` to your program arguments.
When developing it is sometimes useful to use option `-debug` and `-consoleLog` also.

Answer (score 2):

Add the option -console to your program arguments.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming late to the party...
In addition to org.eclipse.equinox.console you also need the **org.eclipse.pde.ui** plugin to be selected in your launch configuration.  Use the 'Validate plugins' button as this generates some additional dependencies of its own (in Eclipse 2021-06) this list is:

- org.eclipse.pde.launching
- org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation
- org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui
- org.eclipse.jdt.junit
- org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core
- org.eclipse.jdt.junit.runtime
- org.eclipse.jdt.ui
- org.eclipse.ant.launching
- org.eclipse.ant.ui
- org.eclipse.ui.trace
- org.junit
- org.hamcrest.core

You don't need to specify -console in the program arguments.